# Why is only LCtrl+Left and LShift+left not working?

Tags: keyboard

On Linux (Kali), I have a strange behavior lately (I haven't noticed it earlier):

- <kbd>RCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> works
- <kbd>RCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> works
- <kbd>RShift</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> works
- <kbd>RShift</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> works
- <kbd>LCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> works
- <kbd>LCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> **does not work**
- <kbd>LShift</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> works
- <kbd>LShift</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> **does not work**
- <kbd>RCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>RShift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> works (selected next word)
- <kbd>LCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>RShift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> works (same)
- <kbd>LCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>RShift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> **does not work**
- <kbd>LCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>LShift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> **does not work**

So looks like the keys are all working well,
except the <kbd>LCtrl</kbd> / <kbd>LShift</kbd>+<kbd>Left arrow</kbd> combo.

Any idea why this strange behavior occurs?

---

Expected behavior & investigation update:

I expect the <kbd>LCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left arrow</kbd> to behave the same as the <kbd>RCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left arrow</kbd> (or similarly to <kbd>LCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right arrow</kbd>): it should move the cursor to the previous word. We have dug more with a friend, and ended up seeing that using an external keyboard with the same configuration seems to work as expected (both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key + left arrow moves to the previous word), so, I guess this is hardware related to the 1st keyboard (laptop keyboard).

Any advice to fix this "hardwarely" (maybe not the correct Stack Exchange website then, as no longer being Linux-related)?

---

Xev

This is what I got using xev, with doing these physical keyactions:

- Press down <kbd>LCtrl</kbd>
- Press down <kbd>LSHift</kbd>
- Press down <kbd>Left arrow</kbd>
- Release <kbd>Left arrow</kbd>
- Release <kbd>LShift</kbd>
- Release <kbd>LCtrl</kbd>
- Press down <kbd>LCtrl</kbd>
- Press down <kbd>LSHift</kbd>
- Press down <kbd>Right arrow</kbd>
- Release <kbd>Right arrow</kbd>
- Release <kbd>LShift</kbd>
- Release <kbd>LCtrl</kbd>

```
dragon@kaliportable:~$ xev
Outer window is 0x3000001, inner window is 0x3000002

PropertyNotify event, serial 8, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    atom 0x27 (WM_NAME), time 4136398, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 9, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    atom 0x22 (WM_COMMAND), time 4136398, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 10, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    atom 0x28 (WM_NORMAL_HINTS), time 4136398, state PropertyNewValue

CreateNotify event, serial 11, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    parent 0x3000001, window 0x3000002, (10,10), width 50, height 50
border_width 4, override NO

PropertyNotify event, serial 14, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    atom 0x14e (WM_PROTOCOLS), time 4136402, state PropertyNewValue

MapNotify event, serial 15, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    event 0x3000001, window 0x3000002, override NO

ConfigureNotify event, serial 20, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    event 0x3000001, window 0x3000001, (0,0), width 178, height 178,
    border_width 0, above 0x60000b, override NO

PropertyNotify event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    atom 0x1d1 (_NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS), time 4136402, state PropertyNewValue

ReparentNotify event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    event 0x3000001, window 0x3000001, parent 0x600f1f,
    (0,0), override NO

PropertyNotify event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    atom 0x153 (_NET_FRAME_EXTENTS), time 4136413, state PropertyNewValue

ConfigureNotify event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    event 0x3000001, window 0x3000001, (10,37), width 178, height 178,
    border_width 0, above 0x0, override NO

PropertyNotify event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    atom 0x1aa (_GTK_EDGE_CONSTRAINTS), time 4136413, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 31, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    atom 0x156 (_NET_WM_DESKTOP), time 4136421, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    atom 0x19b (WM_STATE), time 4136423, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    atom 0x15c (_NET_WM_STATE), time 4136423, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    atom 0x1aa (_GTK_EDGE_CONSTRAINTS), time 4136423, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    atom 0x1aa (_GTK_EDGE_CONSTRAINTS), time 4136428, state PropertyNewValue

ConfigureNotify event, serial 34, synthetic YES, window 0x3000001,
    event 0x3000001, window 0x3000001, (48,104), width 178, height 178,
    border_width 2, above 0x0, override NO

PropertyNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    atom 0x1aa (_GTK_EDGE_CONSTRAINTS), time 4136442, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    atom 0x15c (_NET_WM_STATE), time 4136443, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    atom 0x1aa (_GTK_EDGE_CONSTRAINTS), time 4136443, state PropertyNewValue

MapNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    event 0x3000001, window 0x3000001, override NO

VisibilityNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    state VisibilityUnobscured

Expose event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    (0,0), width 178, height 10, count 3

Expose event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    (0,10), width 10, height 58, count 2

Expose event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    (68,10), width 110, height 58, count 1

Expose event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    (0,68), width 178, height 110, count 0

FocusIn event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    mode NotifyNormal, detail NotifyNonlinear

KeymapNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  68  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   16  0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

PropertyNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    atom 0x15c (_NET_WM_STATE), time 4136456, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    atom 0x1aa (_GTK_EDGE_CONSTRAINTS), time 4136456, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    atom 0x15c (_NET_WM_STATE), time 4136456, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    atom 0x1aa (_GTK_EDGE_CONSTRAINTS), time 4136456, state PropertyNewValue

KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x116, subw 0x0, time 4137624, (610,103), root:(660,209),
    state 0x10, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x116, subw 0x0, time 4138162, (610,103), root:(660,209),
    state 0x14, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x116, subw 0x0, time 4139610, (610,103), root:(660,209),
    state 0x15, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x116, subw 0x0, time 4140217, (610,103), root:(660,209),
    state 0x14, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x116, subw 0x0, time 4140814, (610,103), root:(660,209),
    state 0x10, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x116, subw 0x0, time 4141468, (610,103), root:(660,209),
    state 0x14, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x116, subw 0x0, time 4142038, (610,103), root:(660,209),
    state 0x15, keycode 114 (keysym 0xff53, Right), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x116, subw 0x0, time 4142177, (610,103), root:(660,209),
    state 0x15, keycode 114 (keysym 0xff53, Right), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x116, subw 0x0, time 4142837, (610,103), root:(660,209),
    state 0x15, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x116, subw 0x0, time 4143460, (610,103), root:(660,209),
    state 0x14, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    mode NotifyNormal, detail NotifyNonlinear

PropertyNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    atom 0x15c (_NET_WM_STATE), time 4145868, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    atom 0x1aa (_GTK_EDGE_CONSTRAINTS), time 4145869, state PropertyNewValue
^C
```

In short, is seems the <kbd>Left arrow</kbd> did nothing, while pressing the <kbd>right arrow</kbd> (while holding LCtrl+LShift in both case) generated some events.

Comment: A bit of information on what you expect to happen is missing here (not everyone is running Kali or is familiar with it but might have some insights none the less).

Comment: Have you tried xev, to see which keys are detected?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor No, I don't see such package in apt; we have used the emboarded "visual" keyboard in the "keyboard parameters", which shows the keyboard layout + highlights the keys when pressed, and LCtrl highlights when pressed alone, and stop highlighting when pressing left arrow at the same time. I've put the comment infos in the question.

Comment: `xev` is part of X. In debian it is in X11-utils. Just try to run it.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor oh, indeed! I've added the xev report for the different keypresses I tried

Comment: What about left arrow on its own?

Comment: Left arrow on its own worked, same as RShift + Left arrow. I can make a xev test, but meanwhile, I had also removed the plastic "grid" of the keyboard and toothe brushed (no toothpaste!) inbetween every key, also removed the left arrow key cleaned it, and replugged it, and LCtrl+Left arrow seems now to work again... I didn't think a physical cleanup would work, because Left arrow alone/RShift+Left arrow/LShift + right arrow  work, but, maybe it was required?! Or maybe I slightly move a contact somewhere when removing the plastic grid case?! Edit: I see I didn't mention it's a laptop